# R loops: merge sheets in a single table and export in excel

Tags: r, excel, loops, join

I am writing a code in R which I'd like to simplify with some loops.
I have 3 excel workbooks (Country1.xlsx, Country2.xlsx, Country3.xlsx) that contains 10 sheets each with exactly the same structure in terms of columns. Currently my code is selecting only one of these files, but I'd like to run the same code for all of them. The idea of the code is the following: the code takes the excel file, import in R some sheets, keeps only some columns from these sheets, and then merge them in a single table that is then exported in excel:

```
setwd("C:/Users/username/Desktop/")
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(writexl)
library(openxlsx)

filename = "Country1.xlsx" #Indicate the file name in your folder
country = "Country1" #Which country refers to

#Import sheets from the excel workbook
ln <- lapply(2:10, function(i) read.xlsx(filename, sheet=i, startRow=1)) #Start from sheet 2 till 10
ln <- setNames(ln, paste0("t_", 2:10)) #Give names to these sheets starting with "t_" and then the number from 2 to 10
list2env(ln, envir=.GlobalEnv) #List the tables

#Rename the columns you need to work with
t_2 <- rename(t_2, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_3 <- rename(t_3, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_4 <- rename(t_4, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_5 <- rename(t_5, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_6 <- rename(t_6, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_7 <- rename(t_7, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_8 <- rename(t_8, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_9 <- rename(t_9, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)
t_10 <- rename(t_10, Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7)

#Extract mini tables with only columns that you need
t_2 <- select(t_2, 1,5,6,7)
t_3 <- select(t_3, 1,5,6,7)
t_4 <- select(t_4, 1,5,6,7)
t_5 <- select(t_5, 1,5,6,7)
t_6 <- select(t_6, 1,5,6,7)
t_7 <- select(t_7, 1,5,6,7)
t_8 <- select(t_8, 1,5,6,7)
t_9 <- select(t_9, 1,5,6,7)
t_10 <- select(t_10, 1,5,6,7)

#Ensure columns are all characters type so you can JOIN them
t_2 <- mutate(t_2, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_3 <- mutate(t_3, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_4 <- mutate(t_4, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_5 <- mutate(t_5, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_6 <- mutate(t_6, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_7 <- mutate(t_7, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_8 <- mutate(t_8, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_9 <- mutate(t_9, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))
t_10 <- mutate(t_10, Number = as.character(Number), Reference = as.character(Reference), Assessment = as.character(Assessment), Comments = as.character(Comments))

#Joint the tables to create a single file with all information
joinfile <- full_join(t_2, t_3)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_4)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_5)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_6)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_7)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_8)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_9)
joinfile <- full_join(joinfile, t_10)

#Kill rows were all values are NAs
joinfile <- joinfile[rowSums(is.na(joinfile)) != ncol(joinfile), ]

#Include at the beginning a column with Country name
joinfile <- data.frame(append(joinfile, c(Country=country), after=0))

#Get rid of previous tables
rm(t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5,t_6,t_7,t_8,t_9,t_10,ln)

#Export the final file in excel
write_xlsx(joinfile, path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/joinfile.xlsx") #I have no idea if it is possible to export giving to the excel the name of a string contained in cell A1 of the joinfile...
```

I am pretty sure most of these actions, being very repetitive, can be simplified with a series of loops...but I don't know how since it's my first time with R. Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your data in a list so that you can apply the same code to different dataframes.

I think the below code should work for any number of files you have in the folder.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

#This should have complete path of all the filenames. 
#For this example Country1.xlsx, Country2.xlsx, Country3.xlsx 
file_path <- list.files('/file/path', pattern = '\\.xlsx$', full.names = TRUE)

#For each file in file_path
map(file_path, ~
  #For each sheet
  map(2:10, function(i) {
    #Read the file with particular sheet nummber
    read.xlsx(.x, sheet=i, startRow=1) %>%
      #Rename column based on position
      rename(Number = 1, Reference = 5, Assessment = 6, Comments = 7) %>%
      #Select specific columns
      select(1,5,6,7) %>%
      #Convert them to character
      mutate(across(.fns = as.character))
  }) %>%
    #Do a full join
    reduce(full_join) %>%
    #Remove all NA rows
    filter(Reduce(`|`, across(.fns = ~!is.na(.)))) %>%
    #Add country column at 1st position
    mutate(Country = tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(.x)), .before = 1) %>%
  #Write the xlsx.
  write_xlsx(path = paste0("C:/Users/username/Desktop/joinfile_", basename(.x))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It gives: `Error in read.xlsx.default(.x, sheet = i, startRow = 1) : 
  File does not exist.` which is strange cause the files are listed correctly (I can see in the environment pane of R that file_path contains the list of xlsx files)

Comment: I think I know why you get the error. Maybe those files are not in your working directory. Use `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files`. See updated answer.